# Python - can't connect client with server (on Windows 2012 R2) using socket module

Tags: python-3.x, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to create simple client-server application using socket module, and if I'm using 'localhost' as a HOST it works well, but when I'm trying to establish connection between my computer and remote Windows Server 2012 R2 client can't connect to server. Here is my scripts:

**SERVER**

```
import socket
HOST = '172.22.5.223' # Windows Server IP
PORT = 9999
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)
print("Listening")
s = server_socket.accept()
print("Connected")
```

**CLIENT**

```
import socket
HOST = '172.22.5.223'
PORT = 9999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
except Exception as e:
    print("Cannot connect to the server:", e)
print("Connected")
```

Error: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: What's the exception you get? Probably the firewall is blocking you? Please provide the exception you print out.

Comment: Also, are you sure about the IP address? I just tested your code (for a client-server connection between 2 machines) and it works without an error. I have Windows 7 though.

Comment: @shadowsheep, I added error message. Ping to server works fine. And also I have MySQL server running on Windows Server and I can connect to it using mysqlconnector.

Comment: @Joey Mallone, server IP is OK (checked using ipconfig, and also connection to MySQL using the same IP works fine), no client IP needed.

Comment: Okay so I'll try to disable windows firewall to a quick check, and if it works then add a firewall rule to allow the connection.

Comment: @shadowsheep, yes, I just disabled firewall and get a connection, thanks.

Comment: Glad to know :-]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a rule to Windows Server firewall to allow server script connect to domain network.